# Origins of the Star Trek World Government: is it the UN?

Tags: star-trek, politics

If I recall correctly, shortly after First Contact, a World Government is created on Earth.  Is it mentioned anywhere if this has its roots in the UN?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's roots don't appear to be in the UN, as there was a period with no overarching government body in that part of the world.  However, it did grow out of Europe.

In 2036, the United Nations was replaced by the [New United Nations](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/New_United_Nations).  There's not much mentioned about it, except that it collapsed by 2079 in the aftermath of the [World War III](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/World_War_III).

The [European Hegemony](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/European_Hegemony) was formed at some point within 50 years after that (at some point before 2123).  Again, not much has been mentioned about its origin, [even on Memory Beta](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/European_Hegemony), but it is what led to [United Earth](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/United_Earth#History) as seen in the 2150s in *Star Trek: Enterprise*.

---

The movie *First Contact* takes place in 2063, during the post-WWIII period when the New United Nations collapsed.  While we don't know when the European Hegemony was created, it was in a different part of the world, and not all countries had signed up to United Earth until 2150 - so even the initial statement in the question depends on how long "shortly after" is.